# Can't load content "Nothing was returned from render"

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to render a fragment from another file into App.js. I can't find anything obvious wrong with this code.

Why on gods green earth does this not work? It worked previously in another project exactly like this, did they change syntax or am I missing something obvious?

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import HomePage from "./pages/HomePage";
import "./App.css";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <HomePage />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

HomePage Fragment

```
import React from "react";

const HomePage = () => {
  <React.Fragment>
    <h1>Hello, welcome to the worst site on earth</h1>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum
    </p>
  </React.Fragment>;
};

export default HomePage;
```

Error:

```
Nothing was returned from render.
```

```
The above error occurred in the <HomePage> component:

    at HomePage
    at div
    at App (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:28:1)
```

[image]

File structure:

[image]

Comment: switch Home component returning  curly braces "{" "}" with parenthesis "(" ")"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You miss return in HomePage, hence the error

> Nothing was **returned** from render.

```
import React from 'react';

const HomePage = () => {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <h1>Hello, welcome to the worst site on earth</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
};

export default HomePage;
```

Comment: So it was something obvious, thank you, still new to react

Comment: no worries, your journey will be long and there will be tons of stuff you will miss, but in the end we all do doesnt matter the experience